# Reverse the order of elements in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.7, reverse, ordereddictionary

If I have a dictionary `dict1 = {1:'a', 2:'c', 'd':'gh'}`
and I want to reverse it so that `dict2 = {'d':'gh', 2:'c', 1:'a'}`. I do not want to change the maping of the dictionary.

I an doing this in python 3.7, which preserves element order in dictionaries. Is there a  function that would do this or what code would allow me to do this.

Answer (score 2):

you can convert to a list `dict1.items` then use the built-in function `reversed`:

```
dict(reversed(list(dict1.items())))
```

output:

```
{'d': 'gh', 2: 'c', 1: 'a'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) to reverse the dictionary:

```
>>> dict1 = {1:'a', 2:'c', 'd':'gh'}
>>> dict2 = dict(reversed(dict1.items()))
>>> dict2
{'d': 'gh', 2: 'c', 1: 'a'}
```

As [@kederrac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60754660/reverse-the-order-of-elements-in-a-dictionary/60754725?noredirect=1#comment107497281_60754725) helpfully pointed out in the comments, the above won't work in Python 3.7, only 3.8. It will trigger a `TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not reversible` exception. To fix this you will need to cast `list()` to `dict1.items()`, as shown in [@kederrac's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60754660/reverse-the-order-of-elements-in-a-dictionary/60758004#60758004) answer. Its probably safe to do this for safer, portable code anyways.

Comment: that, won't work on python 3.7 , you need a sequence to use `reversed` function